# 'Chairs left outside' 'Apples brought to the market'. What type of construction are these sentences?

Tags: grammar

Chairs left outside get taken.

What type of (passive) construction is the sentence above?

And why is it preferred to the present passive construction 'Chairs that are left outside get taken'?

Comment: Preferred in speech for their economy.

Answer (score 3):

> *Chairs [left outside] get taken.*

The bracketed constituent is a past-participial clause modifying "chairs". Past-participials (and gerund-participials) are semantically similar to relative clauses: compare:

*Chairs [that are left outside] get taken.*

But they are not analysed as relative clauses since there's no possibility of them containing a relative phrase (cf.* *Chairs which left outside* ...").

Past-participial modifiers are bare passives as evident from the admissibility of a *by* phrase in internalised complement function (cf. *Chairs left outside by their owners get taken)*.

Comment: +1 I far prefer this analysis to the standard TFG understanding of these as 'reduced relatives'. Personally, I prefer to understand the construction as, say German, does, as an adjectival postposed in English because its head has a following complement; but I'm ornery that way.

Comment: Is this TFG? https://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/annotation/syn-sub.htm#reduced_relatives

Comment: Chairs [that are] left outside get taken. Same meaning with or without "that are" and with or without their owners. That merely shows they are passive. versus: Chairs that rotted away outside got taken. That=introduces the restrictive clause.

Comment: I said "semantically similar"! It's not just a case of "merely showing they are passive". The modifying clauses are structurally different in that relative clause are (almost always) finite, whereas past-participial clauses are non-finite.

Comment: Why is there no such thing as BE-deletion?  These analytical frameworks seem capricious to me.  *water brought to a boil*  is *water <del>which BE</del> brought to a boil*. And why not call it zero-relative instead of  wh-deletion?

Comment: Nice explanation. Sorry @Stoney TFG?

Comment: Mrpeech. TFG = transformational functional grammar. A highly theoretical form - a confused meaning-based mish-mash based largely on Michael Halliday's thinking. Relevant to linguiists, but irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2):

1) Chairs **that are left outside** get taken. **is the same as:**

**Chairs left outside** get taken.

Both are passive constructions, one just omits the "that are".

The chairs that I left outside were taken. = The chairs I left outside were taken.

**[that are] left outside** and **[that] I left outside** are **objects in a relative clause**. They can be left out.

2) We have many chairs **that** rotted away outside. [that is the subject of the relative clause]

**The passive construction is not what counts in terms of leaving out the "that" or that + are/is. It is how it functions in the clause**. **Is the word "that" acting as a subject or not?**If so, it must be left in. See 2) above.

The apples [that are] taken to market are usually very good.

The same logic applies there. It works the same way as explanation 1).

[sorry, but I prefer take here. That's another issue.]

Answer (score 0):

These [reduced relative clauses](http://linguistics.oxfordre.com/view/10.1093/acrefore/9780199384655.001.0001/acrefore-9780199384655-e-185) modify the subject.

> Windows **painted black** are opaque.